# How to solve search in Codeigniter with datatable

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, datatables, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-3

I have a problem in label search when I type some character it shows an error message

My controller :

```
public function ajaxlist()
    {
    $list = $this->eee_model->get_datatables();
    $data = array();
    $no=0;
    foreach ($list as $q) {
        $no++;
        $row = array();
        $row[] = $no;
        $row[] = $q->nofile;
        $row[] = $q->est_no ."/".$q->file_no;
        $row[] = $q->number;
        $row[] = $q->nobilut;
        $row[] = $q->nounit;
        $row[] = $q->zone;
        $row[] = $q->subz;
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="'.site_url($q->file).'" "><i class="fa fa-file-pdf-o"></i></a>';
        $row[] = '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" href="'.site_url("estebyan/edit/".$q->id).'" title="Edit" target="_blank" "><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> edit</a>';
        $row[] =  '<a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Hapus" onclick="delete_person('."'".$q->id."'".')"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> delete</a>';             

        $data[] = $row;
    }

    $output = array(
                    "draw" => $_POST['draw'],
                    "recordsTotal" => $this->estebyan_model->count_all(),
                    "recordsFiltered" => $this->estebyan_model->count_filtered(),
                    "data" => $data,
            );
    //output to json format
    echo json_encode($output);
  }
```

My Model:

```
var $table = 'Edata';
var $column_order = array(null, 'number','nofile','zone','subz','nobilut'); //set column field database for datatable orderable
var $column_search = array('number','nofile','zone','subz','nobilut'); //set column field database for datatable searchable 
var $order = array('id' => 'asc'); // default order 
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
}



private function _get_datatables_query()
{

    $this->db->from($this->table);

    $i = 0;

    foreach ($this->column_search as $item) // loop column 
    {

        if(isset($_POST['search']['value']) ? $_POST['search']['value'] : null)
      // if datatable send POST for search
        {

            if($i===0) // first loop
            {
                $this->db->group_start(); // open bracket. query Where with OR clause better with bracket. because maybe can combine with other WHERE with AND.
                $this->db->like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }
            else
            {
                $this->db->or_like($item, $_POST['search']['value']);
            }

            if(count($this->column_search) - 1 == $i) //last loop
                $this->db->group_end(); //close bracket
        }
        $i++;
    }

    if(isset($_POST['order'])) // here order processing
    {
        $this->db->order_by($this->column_order[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
    } 
    else if(isset($this->order))
    {
        $order = $this->order;
        $this->db->order_by(key($order), $order[key($order)]);
    }
}

function get_datatables()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    if($_POST['length'] != -1)
    $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}

function count_filtered()
{
    $this->_get_datatables_query();
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->num_rows();
}

public function count_all()
{
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

My View:

```
              <table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>nofile</th>
                        <th>fileno</th>
                        <th>number</th>
                        <th>nobulit</th> 
                        <th>unit</th> 
                        <th>Zone</th> 
                        <th>Sub</th> 
                        <th>attach</th> 
                        <th >edit</th> 
                        <th >delete</th> 
                    </tr>
                </thead> 
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

My Script :

```
    table = $('#table').DataTable({ 


    "processing": true, //Feature control the processing indicator.
    "serverSide": true, //Feature control DataTables' server-side processing mode.
    "order": [], //Initial no order.
    // Load data for the table's content from an Ajax source
    "ajax": {
        "url": "<?php echo site_url('estebyan/ajaxlist')?>",
        "type": "POST"
    },

    //Set column definition initialisation properties.
    "columnDefs": [
    { 
        "targets": [ 0 ], //first column / numbering column
        "orderable": false, //set not orderable
    },
    ],

});
```

All view data is displayed but search doesn't work!

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "your url",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){ // return json encode data

            if(data.length > 0){
                tabledata = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    tabledata.push([ // push data in array as per your column
                        data[i].name,
                        data[i].other_value,
                        data.[i].other_value]);
                }
                        if (table != null) table.fnDestroy();
                table = $('#tablename').dataTable({
                    "data": tabledata, // add your data array it will create datatable with search and pagination and other things
                });
            }                           
        },
        error: function(){

        }
    });
```

if you don't have datatable.js and datatable.css so please include first and try this code

Answer (score 0):

you dont have anything in the order array in your datatables_query, try this write this before your order processing.

`$column_order = $this->column_order;`